# how to extract data from binance websockets with ThreadedWebsocketManager?

Tags: python, websocket, binance

I have this code:

```
    from http import client
from operator import index
import asyncio
from binance.streams import ThreadedWebsocketManager, AsyncClient, BinanceSocketManager
import pandas as pd
import config
from binance.client import Client
indexes=[1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5]

def streaming_data_process(msg):
    """
    Function to process the received messages
    param msg: input message
    """
    print(f"message type: {msg['e']}")
    print(f"close price: {msg['c']}")
    print(f"best ask price: {msg['a']}")
    print(f"best bid price: {msg['b']}")
    print("---------------------------")
    return msg



def trade_history(msg):
    ''' define how to process incoming WebSocket messages '''
    if msg['e'] != 'error':
        print(msg)
        print(msg['c'])
        print(msg['E'])
        print(msg['o'])
        print(msg['h'])
        print(msg['l'])
        print(msg['v'])
        btc_price['last'] = msg['c']
        btc_price['bid'] = msg['b']
        btc_price['last'] = msg['a']
        btc_price['error'] = False
        indexes[0]=msg['E']
        indexes[1]=msg['o']
        indexes[2]=msg['h']
        indexes[3]=msg['l']
        indexes[4]=msg['v']
        #indexes[5]=msg['c']
        print(indexes)
        return indexes, btc_price['last']
    else:
        btc_price['error'] = True
        # Aqui quieres devolver algo? O que actualice esto pero no devuelva nada? 
    

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    client = Client(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET, tld='com')
    symbolo='BTCUSDT'
    btc_price = {'error':False}
    #tiempo = msg['E']
    
    # init and start the WebSocket
    bsm = ThreadedWebsocketManager()
    bsm.start()
    
    # subscribe to a stream 
    # Aquí deberías llamar a trade_history con el debido mensaje
    bsm.start_symbol_ticker_socket(callback=trade_history, symbol=symbolo)
```

I need to extract the data from indexes, I need to use the msg[h],[l],[c],[o],[v] and [E]
to use it in this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='ms')
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True, drop=True)
#data = data.drop(data.columns[0],axis=1)

o=df['Open']   = df['Open'].astype(float)
h=df['High']   = df['High'].astype(float)
l=df['Low']    = df['Low'].astype(float)
c=df['Close']  = df['Close'].astype(float)
v=df['Volume'] = df['Volume'].astype(float)
```

what is the correct way to do this, I dont know if its with a json, or how ever the way it needs to be done, but yes, I need to extract the data form msg[E] .... to use it in the df list. how has it to be done?